C++ multiple promises for one task
My use-case is rather common.

I have a class that performs some asynchronous operation: e.g. get some data asynchronously from a service;
I can have multiple requests (get_data calls) for that particular piece data from different threads;
I would like to respond to each with a future so each caller can block at its own leisure until the data was retrieved.

class my_thousand_promises {
public:
  // can be called multiple types from multiple threads
  std::future<data> get_data(key) { ... }

private:
  void handle_data_received(key, data) {
    // unblock all users waiting for data
  }
};

My thought is to associate a concurrency free queue of promises with the data key.
Each time a new call comes for the data I would push a new promise in the queue.
Once the data is received, I would pop and fulfill each made promise.
I'm sure there are probably better solutions for this, hence me being here humbly asking.

What underlying RPC mechanism do you use? If it is gRPC you might want to consider opening a stream instead. Otherwise I would use one thread to fill a buffer with repeated (synchronous gets) and have other threads consume data from there. E.g. use a condition variable to signal new data is available.

Did you notice that there's also a std::shared_future, which allows multiple futures to wait for the same std::promise?

@ChristianStieber no I did not and it's exactly what I need. Thank you very much for pointing that out. Could you please add an answer to the question so I can mark it as the right one?

@PepijnKramer Thank you for your answer, however I don't think the underlying RPC mechanism is relevant for this question which is why I didn't specify it. The real problem here was how to allow multiple "clients" asynchronously request the same data and block until that data is available. You are basically describing a producer/consumer more specifically half sync/half async pattern which would probably be more appropriate for the server side of this.

@andreig1978 I understand your question better now. You could do this by letting get_data do something with std::async and a lambda that will wait for a condition variable.  Then call my_thousand_promises.get_data() which will do the actual grpc call and then sets a condition variable.  (The condition variable waits for two conditions, data_received OR my_thousand_promises destruction signal).

Well, from the looks of it, std::shared_future might do the trick for you: it allows multiple shared_future to be connected to the same std::promise. They also have the same capabilities as a normal future; I suspect the only reason they are a different class is some additional internal complexity that's not needed for the non-shared case.
https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/shared_future
Roughly speaking, you create one normal std::future from a promise, and use its share() call to transfer it to a shared_future. The normal future becomes useless, but you can copy the shared_future as much as you want, so just keep that as your source to generate copies from.

You can also construct a shared future from an rvalue future.
